# How can I set TCP connection timeout using Keep alive in Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, c++17, keep-alive

I have a TCP connection that I want to get fast feedback that the connection is broken.

My device transmits data every second or every couple of seconds (definitely not longer than 4 seconds). There are a few cases that the ethernet connection might get lost and the device doesn't "know" that and it keeps the socket open for many seconds until it is considered broken. If that time was very short I could re-open the socket and start transmitting again.
It takes many seconds until I notice something using `send` and `recv` commands.

From another post here I found the following:

```
ssize_t set = 1;
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&set, sizeof(set)) != 0)
{
    return -1;
}

int keepcnt = 5;
if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &keepcnt, sizeof(keepcnt)) != 0)
{
    return -1;
}

int keepidle = 5;
if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &keepidle, sizeof(keepidle)) != 0)
{
    return -1;
}

int keepintvl = 1;
if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &keepintvl, sizeof(keepintvl)) != 0)
{
    return -1;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything...
I unplug the cable and it still takes a lot of seconds.

Also if I set the values at `1` the connection should consider broken almost immediately but instead it keeps going even if I have the ethernet cable unplugged for 10 seconds or more.
And it resumes when I plug it in.